# RequireJS absolute path produces Script Error

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have a simple file which I'm loading dependencies with requireJS using `define`:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/aspect",
    "local/path/to/myFile"
], function(
    declare,
    aspect,
    myFile
) { ...
```

This works as it should, the files are mapped in the requireJS config.

However, if I try to access one of the files using an absolute path (the exact same file):

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/aspect",
    "https://blah.com/absolute/path/to/myFile.js"
], function(
    declare,
    aspect,
    myFile
) { ...
```

I get the following error:

> "message": "Error: Script error for \"https://blah.com/absolute/path/to/myFile.js\", needed by: /home/test_vds_jasmine/test/modules/myFile-spec4.js\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror\nat /home/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:168:17\n\nmakeError@/home/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:168:17\nnewContext/context.onScriptError@/home/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:1738:36\n"

I've tried all manner of absolute path including with and without `https`, with and without the `.js` extension but am drawing a blank, the error message is not really helpful at all.

Am I calling the absolute path in the wrong way? Has anyone had experience doing it this way?

There's a valid reason why I have to call some files using absolute paths or I would just call all locally.

Comment: See if these help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624503/load-external-scripts-with-requirejs-without-access-to-config, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759151/how-do-i-load-third-party-javascript-from-a-cdn-when-using-requirejs, https://coderwall.com/p/y4vk_q/requirejs-and-external-scripts

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani will try those, thought I'd exhausted everything but the `shim` approach is interesting

Comment: Is `myFiles.js` actually an AMD file that uses `define`? How do you load the main script? Under what URL? Try "break-on-exception" in your debugger and see what the actual problem is. You won't get the stacktrace because of cross-origin restrictions otherwise, most likely there is a simple error in myFiles.js and you just don't see the stacktrace..

Comment: @Sebastian as I said in OP, it works fine if I include it locally as opposed to absolutely, so the file is good, yes the file uses define. Thanks for `break-on-exception` idea

Comment: @DarrenSweeney What's the result of the network request for loading that file? In the debugger, check both the HTTP status on the response and the contents actually transmitted (which could be different from the content you expect). If the network request fails or you get the wrong content then there's nothing RequireJS can do to fix that, and the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney show us the define statement of the loaded file - and the message of the actual exception - Also are there any baseUrl/path definitions in your setup? They will be applied differently if loaded via https... So dependencies will be resolved using a different strategy.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, any update on the link I posted, does it help or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, put your URL in your requirejs config like this:

```
requirejs.config({
        paths: { 'myFileRemote': 'https://blah.com/absolute/path/to/myFile.js' }
    });
```

Now update your file with above mapping:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/aspect",
    "myFileRemote"
], function(
    declare,
    aspect,
    myFile
) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Suggested Solution

Your `myFile.js` should have a define block to be used like that. Upgrade your `myFile.js` with define structure.

**myFile.js:**

```
define(["./cart", "./cart2"], function(cart, cart2) {
    return {
        color: cart.color,
        size: "large",
        addToCart: function() {
        }
    }
});
```

> Alternative Solution

If you cannot modify `myFile.js` to that structure just add it to the `path` of `requirejs` config the way you add `jQuery`. You can add the config at the top of `myFile.js` or `app.js` (the file you are calling `myFile.js` from). If you add config to `app.js`, you can access it from everywhere.

**myFile.js/app.js:**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "myFile": "https://blah.com/absolute/path/to/myFile"
    }
});
```

Then you can use it as follows:

**myFile.js:**

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/aspect",
    "myFile"
], function(
    declare,
    aspect,
    myFile
) { ...
```